# Xdebug - PHP output at each step?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I am using Netbeans with xDebug for php debugging.

There is an output window in Netbeans, I want to know how can I have PHP output at each step or at least something like `print_output($data)` on the output window ?

Answer (score 1):

When you step through the code all generated output will be shown in the `Output` window.

<kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> or `Windows -> Output -> Output` to see the window.